# MCP25625 is not sending CAN messages out from chip

Tags: microchip, can

I was using MCP2515 and now I want to use MCP25625.
I connect the new chip MCP25625 and observe 1st SPI interface and it's working properly because I can read and write register correctly.
The CAN initialization is also set without any error and program starts transmiting CAN messages, but on the other side, I'm unable to receive these messages. The mode is `NORMAL` and status register return `0`.
If anyone has an idea then please share.

Comment: When a CAN message is sent it has to be acknowledged. There is 1 bit time frame as part of the message to do this. Your receiving CAN unit must acknowledge the message.

Comment: A check list of CAN FAQ stuff: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)