# Unable to see data on CANoe tool using MCP25625

Tags: embedded, can

[image]Already someone posted the problem scenario, which I'm facing currently.

I'm using  MCP25625 and using  SPI interface and it's working properly because I can read and write the register correctly.
CAN initialization is also set without any error andThe program starts transmitting CAN message, but on the other side, I'm unable to receive these messages on the other side. The mode is NORMAL and the status register returns 0. Inboard already 120ohm resistor is available. We choosen 20Mhz. Is there any other terminal resistor required?
If anyone has an idea then please share.

Pls find the old link, someone shared already the problem
[MCP25625 is not sending CAN messages out from chip](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/551930/mcp25625-is-not-sending-can-messages-out-from-chip)

Comment: Welcome to the world of CAN! You have a relative common problem and are a long way from providing all the information needed to resolve your problem.Are you doing this on a chip level or a module level. I use the MPC2515 modules and they work great. Are both using the same crystal frequency? Are they set for the same Baud? You have CAN-H and CAN-L are they connected to the same on the other end? The CAN bus is normally 60 Ohms which is normally accomplished by putting a 120 ohm resistor at each physical end. Is this what you have? What Micro are you implementing these with? Post a schematic.

Comment: Updated call the comments,Pls have a look.

Comment: Well, did you go through the link I posted in comments to that other post? [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251) In particular, ensure that you aren't running in some loop back mode and that other CAN nodes are present.